# How to implode newlines/break lines to a space?

Tags: php, regex, string, algorithm, implode

How to implode newlines/break lines to a space?

given these $strings:

```
The quick brown
fox jumps 
over the lazy
dog
```

imploding those strings with a blank space

```
$keys = implode(' ', array_keys($strings));
```

I have this:

```
The quick brownfox jumpsover the lazydog
```

And I'm trying to have this:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Any lights? Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll be wanting to use something along the lines of `"\n"` this indicates a new line.

Comment: Are your strings loaded from a file? Do they contain new line character in the end?

Comment: echo preg_replace("/\n/","",$strings);...and a -1 for being lazy.

Comment: @despina, Not know the solution for something is not laziness. Laziness and ignorance, is do not try find out the solution fearing those who claim that they are the best. And thank for your solution, it worked ;)

Comment: @agaezcode Implode and explode knowledge is enough to solve the problem. You used array_keys and implode so you know array functions. I checked your other questions on SO. You seem a smart person therefore php.net would have brought you to one of the multiple solutions with a little extra effort ;) You are welcome for the solution.

Comment: @despina, you know, sometimes two brains are better than just one. Thank you for your arguments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `preg_replace` for this instead of explode/implode:

```
$s = 'The quick brown
fox jumps
over the lazy
dog';

$s = preg_replace('#[\r\n]#', ' ', $s);

echo $s;
```

Output:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use explode:

```
$strings = <<<TEXT
The quick brown
fox jumps 
over the lazy
dog
TEXT;

$strings = implode(' ', explode("\n", $strings));

echo $strings;
```

If you need more explanation, please let me know :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've solved the problem with preg_replace() and some regex.

Comment: There is nothing bad by using preg_replace, im a big fan of regular expressions. But string functions are faster than regex.

Answer (score 2):

At first you have to explode the string like this

```
$var='The quick brown
fox jumps 
over the lazy
dog';
$data=explode(' ',$var);
```

Then implode the exploded data

```
$string=implode(' ',$data);
```

and finally print it

```
echo $string;
```

I think it works well :)

Comment: I don't think your example works like expected, because you never removes the newlines from the string,

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$strings = "The quick brown
fox jumps 
over the lazy
dog
";

$strings = implode(' ', array_map( 'trim', explode("\n", $strings)));

echo $strings;

?>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your solution. It's alawys nice to see diferent solutions to solve a problem. I've solved it with the preg_replace() function and some regex. Thank you

Comment: Good answer, using array_map to trim the result, i missed. But as a little improvement, you can easily use the trim function directly without wrapping it: `$strings = implode(' ', array_map( 'trim', explode("\n", $strings)));`.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer just nothing, but in my answer I forgot to trim the result.

Comment: @skroczek you think that is a bad solution do this?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer No, imo you have to trim the strings in the array, because with that, you are safe to process windows newline ('\n\r') and the unix newline (just '\n'). Additional you remove possible whitespaces in the front or at the end of the lines, which is missing in the accepted answer.